# vim-airline not displayed correctly

Tags: vimrc, gvim, plugin-airline

My `vim-airline` plugin looks like this:
[image]

But on all screenshots it might be like this:
[image]

Here my Vundle plugins list:

```
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'rking/ag.vim'
Plugin 'skwp/greplace.vim'
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
Plugin 'garbas/vim-snipmate'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'StanAngeloff/php.vim'
Plugin 'arnaud-lb/vim-php-namespace'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'stephpy/vim-php-cs-fixer'
Plugin 'tobyS/vmustache'
Plugin 'tobyS/pdv'
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
```

Some config from my `.vimrc` file, without plugins config:

```
set nocompatible

syntax enable
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set number
let mapleader = ',' 
set noerrorbells visualbell t_vb=           
set autowriteall                    
set complete=.,w,b,u                    
set tabstop=8
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

"------------Visuals-------------"
set background=dark
colorscheme material-theme
set t_CO=256                
set guifont=Operator\Mono\ weight=350\ 10
set linespace=10
set guioptions-=e           

set guioptions-=l           
set guioptions-=L
set guioptions-=r
set guioptions-=R

hi LineNr guibg=bg
set foldcolumn=2
hi foldcolumn guibg=bg

hi vertsplit guifg=bg guibg=bg
```

I using Ubuntu 16.04, try to use gVim and terminal vim, the same.

I try to comment all visual config like theme, guifonr, but the same result.

Comment: the default changed recently. Also if you want those nice little triangles, you need to configure airline to use those poweline glyphs. Read the documentation on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed [powerline/fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) and after the commands:

```
# clone
git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git
# install
cd fonts
./install.sh
# clean-up a bit
cd ..
rm -rf fonts
```

My status looks like better, but not ideal, I think it's because I didn't find my font in that repository, but it`s nit big problem.

Now my panel look like this:
[image: sample]

Comment: That's because of your `linespace` setting. Setting this option to 10 will result in 5 additional rows of pixels both above and below every line, including your status line. This additional rows inherit their background color from the original line.

Answer (score 3):

1. install fonts with powerline symbol.[YaHei-Consolas-Hybrid-For-Powerline](https://github.com/Magnetic2014/YaHei-Consolas-Hybrid-For-Powerline)
2. set your terminal's font  to this font.
3. set guifont and guifontwide to this font in the case gvim & macvim.see [this](https://github.com/tracyone/t-vim/blob/master/rc/gui.vim#L28-L34)
4. set airline symbol.

https://github.com/tracyone/t-vim/blob/master/rc/airline.vim